# Sql Query for Unique and Duplicates in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display unique records in one column and duplicates in another column in Oracle?

```
COL1 COL2
1     10
1     10
2     20
3     30
3     30

unique in one set             duplicate in one set

col1  col2                    col1 col2
2      20                      1    10
                               1    10
                               3    30
                               3    30
```

Comment: Records don't fit into columns.  Please show us sample data along with your current query.

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group by for both cases with the having clause:

Unique records

```
select *
from table as t
inner join (
select col1, col2, count(*) as times
from table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) = 1) as t2 ON t.col1 = t2.col2 and t.col2 = t2.col2
```

Duplicate records:

```
select *
from table as t
inner join (
select col1, col2, count(*) as times
from table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1) as t2 ON t.col1 = t2.col1 and t.col2 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do? See comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col1, col2) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 10 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 10 from dual union all
  6     select 2, 20 from dual union all
  7     select 3, 30 from dual union all
  8     select 3, 30 from dual
  9    ),
 10  uni as
 11    -- unique values
 12    (select col1, col2
 13     from test
 14     group by col1, col2
 15     having count(*) = 1
 16    ),
 17  dup as
 18    -- duplicate values
 19    (select col1, col2
 20     from test
 21     group by col1, col2
 22     having count(*) > 1
 23    )
 24  -- the final result
 25  select u.col1 ucol1,
 26         u.col2 ucol2,
 27         d.col1 dcol1,
 28         d.col2 dcol2
 29  from uni u full outer join dup d on u.col1 = d.col1;

     UCOL1      UCOL2      DCOL1      DCOL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
                               1         10
                               3         30
         2         20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the duplicate values using window functions, and then filter each query.  Then to get unique records:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

To get duplicates:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```